# Class not Registered Error on Visual Studio 2017 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mysql-connector

I am migrating my standalone VB.NET developed Windows Forms Application from SQL to MySQL and while doing that I am using an online database. Here is the scenario.

1. Application is developed in Visual Studio 2017 VB.NET and is a Windows Forms Application.
2. My database is hosted on Hostinger.

Now obviously, If I want to connect to MySQL from VS, I need two components.

1. MySQL for Visual Studio
2. Visual Studio MySQL Connector

And here the problem begins, I tried various versions of both components but still, I am getting the following error.

[image]

Now as per online forums and questions answered here, this error occurs when software component not installed on the machine. In this case, I am using MySQL references but either MySQL connector or MySQL for VS not installed. But that's not the case. I have both of these installed.

I tried to manually update diff version of MySQL.Data.DLL (v4.0 and v4.5) but nothing seems to solve the problem.

I tried the same project with VS 2015 Community but still not working.

Read different forums and tried multiple solutions. Posting question here is kind of my last resort.

I think for this to work, specific versions of both supporting software must be installed. If anyone has tried this before, working on this or have any workarounds, Let me know.

And just because, question title is somewhat common and mentioned many times on multiple posts, just don't duplicate it without having a proper solution.

> Additional Problem: MySQL does not show in Server Explorer' server
>   list. This is optional.

UPDATE :

> Installing **MySQL for VS 1.2.7** and **MySQL Connector 6.10.5** will enable the option in Server Explorer' server list. Now I can Create New MySQL Connection using this. I have successfully created a remote MySQL connection and tested it but still having the above error when trying to run the project.

Comment: This may be a silly questions, but, do you have MySQL installed on your machine and can you connect to it from its Workbench software?

Comment: Yes, I have. But still, it should be out of the question. I am connecting to remote MySQL from VS. I mean, do I really need to have MySQL installed on the local machine?

And btw, I can connect to my remote DB from Workbench, the same I am trying to connect using VS.

Comment: @JayV : Your thoughts? Would you mind telling me why you asked that?

Comment: 1. You listed two items as pre-requisites but not the MySQL database server (whether it is a local or remote is not important). 2. When diagnosing DB connection issues, confirming the DB server is available using other means is a good way to confirm the DB server works

Comment: @JayV : Ok, thanks for the clarification. Do you have any idea about my problem though? Anything I can try?

Comment: Also, can you confirm if you have the correct MySQL Connectors for Version and Platform (ADO.NET or ODBC)? Also checking for 32/64bit related problems. If all of this checks out, only other thing I can think of is a failed installation meaning uninstall of all MySQL components and removal from the file system and then re-install

Comment: @JayV: As I mentioned in the question, I tried multiple connectors but nothing seemed to work. Obviously, I repaired all the installations.

It's an ADO.NET Connection and tried both x86 and x64 debug outputs.

Do you know which connector will work with this?

Comment: When I did some MySQL work a few weeks ago I used v8 of MySQL and its support bits (Community Server, Connecter/ADO.Net, Connector/ODBC, Router). I had a failed installation, but I didn't Repair it. I uninstalled and deleted folders then re-installed.

Comment: Ok. Will try. Can you tell me the exact version you used?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not on Framework 4.6 or greater you will need a legacy MySql connector. To use the most recent version of the connector, remove all refernces and imports, close Visual studio, uninstall the current connector, and MySQL for Visual Studio and install the latest version of the connector. Do not install MySQL for Visual Studio, you do not need it unless you're into building apps via the designer. Change your framework to 4.6+ and add reference to to MySql.Data and import the namespace. If this does not solve the issue I will delete this answer.

Comment: Thanks. Will try now.

Comment: I did exactly what you said. Now I am getting this error: **BC2017 could not find library '..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.10\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll'** AND **BC2017 could not find library '..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.10\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll' **
. though I don't have this folder on machine or reference in the project. Clicking on error doesn't do anything. Any idea?

Comment: You get that message when you try to add the reference?

Comment: No, when compiling

Comment: have you "cleaned" the solution? (for both debug and release)

Comment: Yeah, obviously. After that, for clearing these errors, created above folders manually, pasted those files in them, registered them using command **gacutil**. Now those errors are gone but still facing above error mentioned in question.

Comment: I've learned when helping people debug, nothing is obvious. Personally I would not have manually registered the libraries, or created those folders. Sorry I could not help you with this problem. I feel you were on the way to resolution clear up till you did that. I will delete this soon.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I would not suggest deleting this solution. This discussion of ours might help other people. Consider.

Comment: @Mahadev ok, it shall remain as per your request

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a COM error. Those are always a joy to debug. Apparently, the MySQL .net provider is using COM under the hood, perhaps to talk to native code.

I don't have a solution, I have zero MySQL experience from .net, and I detest VB with a passion. So, I probably am not your savior, but here are some tips and advice that might help track down the COM error. These are kind of a last resort

1. Download and install [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) and [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from Microsoft. Process Monitor allows you to snoop on file and registry access. DbgView captures log messages from `OutputDebugString`. If you are lucky, MySQL native code might be emitting debug strings.
2. Create a simple, bare bones console mode application that exhibits the problem.

   - Print a boot message as soon as your main method starts. Include the value of `Environment.Is64BitProcess` in the message (will explain why below)
   - Wait for the user to press a key via `Console.ReadKey()`. This is to give you time to setup process monitor
   - Try to connect to MySQL after the key press. Surround every statement with copious logging.
   - Configure Visual Studio to only target x64 code if you are on a 64 bit machine
3. Start DebugView
4. Run your app outside of the debugger (stick with Debug builds though)
5. While it is waiting for the key press, start Process Monitor and tell it to only log events from your application
6. Press a key in your test application and see if it blows up like your winforms app did
7. Assuming it crashes, look at Process Monitor to see what was going on at the moment of the crash. There will probably be a mountain of junk. You will have to filter down to registry and file access. Focus on operations that failed. Procmon will allow you to see the filename and registry keys that were accessed.
8. Look at the logging in DebugView and see if anything interesting popped up

Ok, so why force 64 bit and log proof that you are in 64 bit mode at runtime? A 64 bit windows machine has both a 64 registry and a 32 bit registry. It is possible for a COM library to be registered in one and not the other. You want to eliminate that headache from the equation. The `Any CPU` target combined with the `Prefer 32-bit` VS settings just add confusion to everything. Best to know for certain what CPU target you are running on while you debug this.

Another tip is to run in the debugger and force it to Break All when that error dialog appears. I don't know if that error box will appear when the console mode app fails, but if it does, the callstack might help point you in the right direction.

One last tip: configure VS for native debugging and tell it to break on all exception types, not just .NET exceptions.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer and efforts. I'll try this and let you know the results.